# Newly created Websphere profile is not showing in RAD after creation

Tags: websphere, rad

I need to create a new profile in websphere application server.I am using profile management tool and it is sucessfully creating. But when i am trying to add new server in RAD the new server is not showing in the dropdown in RAD.I have also used profilemanagement .bat file and command promt to create new profile but noting is working for me.The profiles are created but none of them are coming in the dropdown in RAD.I have a question here , i read some blogs where people are saying i have to change the SOAP and RMI port i am changing the SOAP port during profile craetion but RMI port i can not change , i don't find anywhere the option also.Please help i have tried almost every thing from my end.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen behaviour like this before on Windows. The scenario I saw back then was caused by permission issues. The profiles were created with admin privileges, but RAD was not being run as an administrator, so the profiles don't show up in RAD (RAD only shows profiles the user can actually use). It was resolved by running RAD as an administrator. Let me know if running RAD as an administrator helps resolve the problem. Thanks